# Split a large decimal number using shift operator

Tags: c, data-structures, bit-shift

> **How to write a program in c to split a large number using shift operator ?**

For example we need to split a large number like 12345678 into two smaller digits 1234 and 5678 using only bit shift operations and not using the normal n=n*10 and n=n%10 technique. How would you do that?

Comment: Did you not have to sign an NDA for your interview?

Comment: what is meant by `split`? give a simple example with numbers

Comment: *That* number or **any** number with a digit-count evenly divisibly by two? (the fulfillment of the latter being the particularly taxing problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard long division algorithm and call it with 12345678 and 10000. If you want to optimize it for dividing by 10000 only, pre-evaluate it for b == 10000 by hand.

```
void div(int a, int b) {
    int d, res;
    d = 1;
    res = 0;
    while (b > 0 && b < a) {
        b <<= 1;
        d <<= 1;
    }

    do {
        if (a >= b) {
            a -= b;
            res += d;
        }
        b >>= 1;
        d >>= 1;
    } while (d);

    printf("Result: %d, reminder: %d\n", res, a);
}

int main() {
    div(12345678, 10000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert number to [BCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) representation and then use shift operations to split them into two variables.

[BCD Conversion](http://www.eng.utah.edu/~nmcdonal/Tutorials/BCDTutorial/BCDConversion.html) using shift operator only.

Comment: How do you make BCD conversion without using division?

Comment: BCD Conversion added to answer.

Comment: Provide extract of linked articles.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer